# Thread.Sleep(); sleeps all the program

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep, ui-thread

I have a problem with the progress bars, I want to run two progress bar like I do in the following code:

```
namespace probando
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

            int sec = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string stringSec = sec.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i <= sec; i++)
            {
                masuno(i,sec);
            }

        }

        private void Tiempo_segundos_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            sec = (int) Tiempo_segundos.Value;
        }

        private void masuno(int i, int sec)
        {
           Porcentaje_restante.Maximum = sec;

           Porcentaje_restante.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Porcentaje_restante.Value = i, DispatcherPriority.Background);

           Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have another progressbar which is indeterminate buy doesn´t work while the first bar is working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8710218/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Sleep pauses the current thread.

From your code i assume you are using this in a windows forms or wpf application , right?

Now there is only a single ui thread. Now when you sleep in the ui thread the whole ui is paused. So you have to put worker code which is not the ui in a background thread.

See alsp this question:
[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) or [How to update UI from another thread running in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602567/how-to-update-ui-from-another-thread-running-in-another-class)

and this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx) about the Threading Model

Answer (score 0):

If `Sleep` is used to delay something in UI thread (to simulate work, to split something, whatever), then you can use `async/await` to do that properly (`Sleep` is blocking UI thread):

```
async void masuno(int i, int sec)
{
    ...

    // Thread.Sleep(1000); - instead of this do:
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: If i do this, the program doesn´t wait every second to update, it makes all together. I don´t know why...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is designed for this kind of scenario. It runs your long process on a background thread and lets you perform UI updates as the progress changes.